# MySQL notifications: SELECT IN vs separate table?

Tags: mysql

I'm building an SQL database with a notifications function where users can get notifications from other users they're subscribed to. My question is, what is the better practice: not having a notifications table and doing it all through SELECT IN(sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5+) or having a notifications table where a new row will be inserted for each subscriber?

I'm worried about this because, if the subscriber count is too high (let's say, 100 subscribers), using SELECT IN can slow down the select process, meanwhile, storing 100 different rows for every time a user posts an update seems like it can easily flood the server.

So, what would you choose personally? And what is the "better" practice overall?

Comment: I don't see how the flooding the server part matters, since the information of subscribers has to get across in both cases.  MySQL can optimize `WHERE IN` better than you might think, but if you have a very long list, then yes I would probably go with a separate table, index it, and then join.

Comment: It matters because, imagine this: Someone with a thousand or so subscribers posts an update. If SELECT IN is used, then it's just one row in one table. If another table is used, then it's a thousand and one rows in separate tables, and a thousand and one more for the next time he posts an update. Meanwhile, MySQL might have to do a SELECT IN with a thousand different values, and these values are probably gonna have to get fetched to boot. That's what I'm worried about.

Comment: I don't know/understand enough about your problem to comment further.

Comment: If there is no separate notifications table, then how would you store the fact that a given user needs to be notified?

Comment: @Shadow, the update would become visible on the main page and be put on top, as it's sorted by time.

Comment: @Ali you got the question wrong. How would you store the notifications in the database if not in a separate table?

Comment: Let's say it's like YouTube. There's a "videos" table, and every time a new video is uploaded, a row is inserted into the "videos" table. The user can see the video in the top of the main page, because the page uses a SELECT IN query sorted by descending time with all the people the user is subscribed to. My question is, is this a good practice, or should I have a separate table where there's a separate row inserted for each subscriber, so that they all don't have to perform SELECT IN?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to advice you use **separate tables** and **inner join** to get all intersections as you need. I believe, It's fast and flexible solution.